# Linkrot - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm getting a "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'" when running a python script. Below is the Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python38\Scripts\linkrot.exe_main.py", line 7, in
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot\cli.py", line 215, in main
text = get_text_output(pdf, args)
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot\cli.py", line 126, in get_text_output
for k, v in sorted(pdf.get_metadata().items()):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'.
```

Here is the snippet of the code throwing the error. I understand why it is wrong, but I'm unsure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def get_text_output(pdf, args):
    """ Normal output of infos of linkrot instance """
    # Metadata
    ret = ""
    ret += "Document infos:\n"
    for k, v in sorted(pdf.get_metadata().items()):
        if v:
            ret += "- %s = %s\n" % (k, parse_str(v).strip("/"))

    # References
    ref_cnt = pdf.get_references_count()
    ret += "\nReferences: %s\n" % ref_cnt
    refs = pdf.get_references_as_dict()
    for k in refs:
        ret += "- %s: %s\n" % (k.upper(), len(refs[k]))

    if args.verbose == 0:
        if "pdf" in refs:
            ret += "\nPDF References:\n"
            for ref in refs["pdf"]:
                ret += "- %s\n" % ref
        elif ref_cnt:
            ret += "\nTip: You can use the '-v' flag to see all references\n"
    else:
        if ref_cnt:
            for reftype in refs:
                ret += "\n%s References:\n" % reftype.upper()
                for ref in refs[reftype]:
                    ret += "- %s\n" % ref

    return ret.strip()
```

Comment: Filter out the `None`s before sorting?

Comment: That was my thinking. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you need the sorting?

Comment: Yes. It sorts the list by error codes. Groups them together.

Comment: So I assume `pdf.get_metadata()` returns a dictionary. Are all the keys of that dictionary strings?

Comment: It returns the collected metadata from a PDF document. Here is a link to the entire file if you'd like to take a wider look.

Comment: https://github.com/marshalmiller/linkrot/blob/main/linkrot/cli.py

Comment: Are you sure a `None` isn't somehow one of the keys of this dictionary? Because since all keys in a dictionary have to be unique, I don't think the sort function should ever compare the values in the dictionary.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Try printing `pdf.get_metadata()` before the for loop. Maybe there's a bug somewhere else in the program that leads to putting something under the key `None`. Would explain everything.

Comment: I gave that a try. The metadata did print. But I still received the same error.

Comment: Well can you add the metadata to the question? Or just check if there is something under the key `None`? Or try to just do `print(pdf.get_metadata()[None])`. What does that print? Does it raise a `KeyError`?

Comment: No KeyError. It did print this.

{'d2UUdod77ndf.zguGmgv.z8NNzt-OlwiSnPmGz.r_mt3_z.n7mt-Ro9ePnt6JmtuRm9iTma': None}

Comment: Perhaps I tried the wrong file. it appears like I'm getting a KeyError: None.

Comment: And with the correct file, the one that raises `KeyError`, does you code now work?

Comment: It does not. I just receive both errors now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `None` is one of the dictionary keys. Since the `sort` method uses comparison to sort the dictionary by keys, it fails because it cannot compare this `None` to the other keys that are strings (thus the error message that talks about a comparison operator `<`).

Assuming the `None` key is there by accident and doesn't contain any useful data, you can solve this by simply removing it from the dictionary before the for loop like this:

```py
metadata = pdf.get_metadata()
metadata.pop(None, None)
for k, v in sorted(metadata.items()):
    ...
```